# Direct convertation between ascii byte[] and int

Tags: c#, parsing, binary, arrays

I have a program which reads bytes from the network. Sometimes, those bytes are string representations of integer in decimal or hexadecimal form.

Normally, I parse this with something like

```
var s=Encoding.ASCII.GetString(p.GetBuffer(),0,(int)p.Length);                                      
int.TryParse(s, out number);
```

I feel that this is wasteful, as it has to allocate memory to the string without any need for it.

Is there a better way I  can do it in c#?

**UPDATE**

I've seen several suggestions to use `BitConverter` class. This is not what I need. BitConverter will transform binary representation of int (4 bytes) into int type, but since the int is in ascii form, this doesn't apply here.

Comment: While you could manually parse the bytes by hard-coding a mapping between ASCII digits and their raw byte equivalent, it probably isn't worthwhile unless you have a convincing reason to believe this is a performance bottleneck.

Comment: Have you tried the basic .NET support for converting a byte array into a another type?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384066.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt it will have a substantial impact on performance or memory consumption, but you can do this relatively easily. One implementation for converting decimal numbers is shown below:

```
private static int IntFromDecimalAscii(byte[] bytes)
{
    int result = 0;

    // For each digit, add the digit's value times 10^n, where n is the
    // column number counting from right to left starting at 0.
    for(int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; ++i)
    {
        // ASCII digits are in the range 48 <= n <= 57. This code only
        // makes sense if we are dealing exclusively with digits, so
        // throw if we encounter a non-digit character
        if(bytes[i] < 48 || bytes[i] > 57)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Non-digit character present", "bytes");
        }

        // The bytes are in order from most to least significant, so
        // we need to reverse the index to get the right column number
        int exp = bytes.Length - i - 1;

        // Digits in ASCII start with 0 at 48, and move sequentially
        // to 9 at 57, so we can simply subtract 48 from a valid digit
        // to get its numeric value
        int digitValue = bytes[i] - 48;

        // Finally, add the digit value times the column value to the
        // result accumulator
        result += digitValue * (int)Math.Pow(10, exp);
    }

    return result;
}
```

This can easily be adapted to convert hex values as well:

```
private static int IntFromHexAscii(byte[] bytes)
{
    int result = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; ++i)
    {
        // ASCII hex digits are a bit more complex than decimal.
        if(bytes[i] < 48 || bytes[i] > 71 || (bytes[i] > 57 && bytes[i] < 65))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Non-digit character present", "bytes");
        }
        int exp = bytes.Length - i - 1;

        // Assume decimal first, then fix it if it's actually hex.
        int digitValue = bytes[i] - 48;
        // This is safe because we already excluded all non-digit
        // characters above
        if(bytes[i] > 57) // A-F
        {
            digitValue = bytes[i] - 55;
        }

        // For hex, we use 16^n instead of 10^n
        result += digitValue * (int)Math.Pow(16, exp);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Oops! You're right of course. Edited to make it clear that the first method only handles decimal.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that this will most likely not have substantial impact on performance or memory consumption. Also, CLR does [string interning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.string.intern(v=vs.110).aspx), so _"it has to allocate memory"_ is not necessarily correct.

Comment: Good point about string interning, but it's worth pointing out that while the CLR *supports* string interning, strings generated at runtime are not usually interned. [This demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bJCqln) shows that the runtime backing .netfiddle doesn't intern runtime strings.

Comment: Interesting, didn't know that. So the official MSDN documentation that I linked is plain wrong then. _"(...) contains a single reference to each unique literal string declared or created programmatically in your program. Consequently, an instance of a literal string with a particular value only exists once in the system. (...)"_ Not correct, really.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could be a little less wasteful (at least in the number of source code characters sense) by avoiding the s declaration like:

```
int.TryParse(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(p.GetBuffer(),0,(int)p.Length), out number);
```

But, I think the only other real way to get a speed-up would be to do as the commenter suggests and hard code a mapping into a Dictionary or something. This could save some time if you have to do this a lot, but it may not be worth the effort...

Comment: Why not just use the BitConverter class?

Comment: That was suggested as an answer and deleted because bitconverter does not convert string representations of data (like a literal "ffffffff" string for -1) to integers.

Comment: Writing it down like that won't do anything for memory needing to be allocated for the string. I'm trying to avoid that

Comment: Yes, that's true. I don't have a better answer, hopefully someone else does. Can you not try the Dictionary approach?

Comment: Side note: please don't copy question into answer (edited out).

Comment: Why not? The OP edited the question and I want my answer to reflect the question that was asked originally.

Comment: @hft You certainly don't need a dictionary. ASCII is much simpler than that. I went ahead and added an answer showing an example of how to do the conversion directly

Comment: You don't *need* a Dictionary, but if the one time cost of a Dictionary is not an issue it may be a cleaner way to do it...